# What is the proper way to test a Rails controller's action that is using throw :async?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, thin

I have a Rails server running on Thin and an async controller action. I would like to test it using RSpec, but I am getting an error:

```
 Failure/Error: get :access_token
     ArgumentError:
       uncaught throw :async
```

This is a sample code:

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController

  def sample
    EM.defer do
      render json: { response: 'Hello World' }

      request.env['async.callback'].call response
    end

    throw :async
  end

end

require 'spec_helper'

describe SampleController, :type => :controller do
  it "hello world" do
    get :sample
    expect(JSON.parse(response.body)[response]).to eq('Hello World')
  end
end
```

The reason why I get this error is because :async can only be handled by Thin server. There is no Thin server available in a vanilla Rails controller.

So tried Capybara:

```
  describe "GET /sample", type: feature do
    it "hello world" do
      visit sample_path

      expect(JSON.parse(page.body)['response']).to eq('Hello World')
    end
  end


  # In spec_helper.rb
  Capybara.server do |app, port|
    require 'rack/handler/thin'
    Rack::Handler::Thin.run(app, :Port => port)
  end
```

But I still get the same error. I believe it is because Thin needs to be started in threaded mode; and capybara does no start it in such a way.

What is the proper way to test a controller's action that is using throw :async?

The action does work when I use a regular browser to get to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to test an asynchronous Ruby on Rails action implemented with Thin you will need to run the test using Thin. Otherwise it will fail, or be brittle – in case you try mocking things up.

So let's set it up using Capybara:

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'thin'
gem 'capybara'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

In spec/rails_helper.rb:

```
require 'capybara/rails' 

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

Capybara.server do |app, port|
  require 'rack/handler/thin'
  Rack::Handler::Thin.run(app, :Port => port)
end
```

That sets the Capybara driver to be selenium, a real browser. The second part configures the Capybara server to be Thin.

The test should be written then as this:

```
describe SampleController, :type => :feature do
  it "my test" do
    visit sample_path
    expect(page).to have_content('Hello World')
  end
end
```

And this will make the test pass.

Answer (score -1):

In your RSpec controller test, try replacing

```
get :sample
```

with

```
expect { get :sample }.to throw_symbol(:async)
```

That should catch it and prevent the spec from failing. It also tests that the controller is async!

Comment: That makes the test fail. `NoMethodError: undefined method 'call' for nil:NilClass`. Which comes from the call `request.env['async.callback'].call response`

Comment: Need a full backtrace to help.

Comment: /Users/Nerian/projects/async_test/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10:in `block in example_async': undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  #   from /Users/Nerian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:1037:in `call'
  #   from /Users/Nerian/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:1037:in `block in spawn_threadpool'

Comment: The issue is that rails uses plain old rack to handle requests in test. The `throw :async` is not handled by rails, but by Thin. Even if we were to catch that :throw, there is still the issue of `request.env['async.callback']` being null, hence the `undefined method 'call' for nil:NilClass`.